# What is difference between $O(|V|+|E|)$ and $O(|V+E|)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, asymptotics

> Perform DFS over the entire graph. The linear time taken by a size of graph as visiting each node finished is put it on the head of initially empty list is

1. $O(|V|+|E|)$
2. $O(|V+E|)$
3. $O(|V|^k)$
4. $O(\log |V|)$

---

My attempt: There is no doubt answer is $O(|V|+|E|)$.

But, what is difference between $O(|V|+|E|)$ and $O(|V+E|)$? Are these same?

> Can you explain, please?

Comment: $O(|V+E|)$ doesn't make any sense assuming $V$ is the set of vertices and $E$ is the set of edges. As a general rule we don't have addition defined on sets.

Comment: $(|V|+|E|)$ can not be negative. And, $(|V+E|)$ is also positive. But can we conclude that $$(|V|+|E|)\geq (|V+E|)?$$

Comment: Assuming that $V$ and $E$ are numbers (which the aren't, they are sets) then yes you could conclude that. It's an easy property of the absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to disagree with the answer by Newb slightly, but mainly just to point out some issues with formalism. Also if you answered $O(|V+E|)$ on my test you would get zero points and I'm sure there are other teachers like that.

Since $V$ and $E$ are sets (exactly what kind depends on your particular definition of graph but the most prevalent definition in the US seems to be $E\subseteq V\times V$ and $V$ arbitrary), then under usual circumstances $V+E$ makes no sense, as you probably haven't defined addition on sets. You could define $V+E=V\cup E$ but it is decidedly non-standard.

For this reason $O(|V+E|)$ is undefined and thus nonsense. Note that the $|\;\;|$ operator here is not the absolute value, instead it is the cardinality operator.